# In what circumstances a patch of event attendees can lead to the deletion of said event in Google Calendar?

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api

I developed an application for the school I work for that create a bridge between our registration system and Google Calendar. In short, it populates multiple calendars (teachers, students, classrooms, and a calendar that contain all courses) based on data from the registration system, it allows teacher to register student attendance and homework for each class and it does a bunch of other stuff.

The application also allows a teacher to trigger an update of the student list when he notices a registered student is not entered as an attendant in the calendar events.

In the code:

1. I make a call to the registration system to get the updated list of students for the course.
2. I make a call to Google Calendar to get the recurrences of the events that represent the course in the calendar.
3. I make a call to Google Calendar to batch patch the "attendees" array of every recurrence

   ```
   this.updateEvent = function(calendarId, eventId, resource)
   {
     return $window.gapi.client.calendar.events.patch({
       calendarId: calendarId, 
       eventId: eventId,
       resource: resource
     });
   };

   this.batchUpdateEvents = function(calendarId, eventList)
   {
     var counter = 0;
     var batchPromises = [];
     for(var i=0; i < eventList.length; i++)
     {
       if(counter === 0)
       {
         var batch = $window.gapi.client.newBatch();
       }

       var event = eventList[i];
       batch.add(this.updateEvent(calendarId, event.id, event.resource), {id: event.id});
       counter++;

       if(counter === 50 || i === eventList.length-1)
       {
         counter = 0;
         batchPromises.push(batch.then());
       }
     }

     return $q.all(batchPromises).then(
       function(response){
         var updateResults = {};
         response.forEach(function(batchResponse){
         updateResults = Object.assign(updateResults, batchResponse.result);
       });

       return updateResults;
     });
   };
   ```

It works fine in most cases but regularly all the calendar events associated with the course are deleted. I can't figure out how to reproduce the bug and since everything is coded in javascript I can't log the errors.

In this process, this is the only 2 times my application interacts with Google Calendar. I really don't see how a [get](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/get) request could delete anything so I assume the batch of [patch](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/patch) requests is the problem. Although the only thing I include in the patch is the attendee array so its actually hard to mess it up to that point.

Has anybody got an idea of the direction I should look into? I am a bit at loss here.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that batchUpdateEvents could be receiving a valid calendarId, but an eventList with blank values. If that's the case checking for a valid value in eventList[0].resource before proceeding to the for loop would prevent blank event values from being saved (which might be causing Google to delete the event). If this script should only add events and never delete them it could also be beneficial to check event.resource before adding it to the batch.

Comment: I think it's unlikely that's the problem I am looking for but I am going to test it anyway and let you know. Nonetheless, you are right on the fact that I should test the presence of eventList[0].resource somewhere.